# Convert a String to a Number Only

Tags: string, bash, integer

I read in two numbers from a user but the number is a string.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter first number: " num1
read -p "Enter second number: " num2
```

I know you can use the the "expr" or "bc" command to automatically convert the string to a number then add them together.  But I don't want to add these numbers, I just want to convert the string to a number.  That's it.  How would I go about doing this?  thank you

Comment: [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232384/argument-string-to-integer-in-bash](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232384/argument-string-to-integer-in-bash)

Comment: Did you try googling your problem?

Comment: Even if you "convert" it to a number, bash still only handles strings and arrays.

Comment: There are no "types" in bash in the classic sense. Variables in bash are always stored internally as strings. When you want to do number operations, the string is interpreted as a base 10 literal integer, but in the end, it winds up back as a string that represents the new value.

Comment: If the number will always remain as a string after the conversion.  Is there not a work around this???  I just want to get 2 numbers from a user and pass those 2 numbers to a function.  That's it.